# Android SafeArgs Navigation Unreslved Reference camelcase kotlin vs underscore xml

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation, android-navigation-graph, android-safe-args

I have a fragment that uses:

```
 val action = LoginFragmentDirections.actionLoginToHome()
        findNavController().safeNavigate(action)
```

and the Navigation graph XML is declared as:

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/loginFragment"
        android:name="com.myapp.LoginFragment"
        android:label="login_fragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/login_fragment">

        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_login_to_home"
            app:destination="@+id/homeFragment"
            app:launchSingleTop="true"
            app:popUpTo="@navigation/nav_graph_main"
            app:popUpToInclusive="false" />

    </fragment>
```

The Android studio compiler doesn't throw any errors and I can even navigate from the `actionLoginToHome()` function to the XML file by using cmd click. However, when building the app the gradle compilation throws the error:

```
**Unresolved reference: actionLoginToHome**
```

Root Gradle:

```
classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.5.2"
```

Module Gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'
}
```

... dependencies ..

```
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.5.2"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.5.2"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok Solved,

The graph was a nested XML of several navigations, one of the navigation fragments in the nested files had the same ID and action than the one with the problem, probably due to a wrongful copy paste.